# Debug Kit doesn't load in CakePHP 3.5.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

After a fresh installation of CakePHP 3.5.4. I have configured the following settings:
In app.php

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

In Bootstrap.php

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true]);
    Plugin::load('DebugKit');
}
```

After That if I hit into the home page, I don't see any debug kit icon.

If anyone face the same issue and resolve this, please reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance that DEBUG is actually defined as false in your environment?

Comment: In my env file : export DEBUG="true" . Thanks for your query. If you face the problem and find solution for it, please let me know. :)